# Pass filename for command execution

Tags: java

I am searching files based on extension. Now for each file found, want to run a command:

Lets assume file found: `C:\Home\1\1.txt`. My exe exists in: `C:\Home\Hello.exe`

I would like to run command something like: "`C:\Home\Hello.exe C:\Home\1\1.txt`"

similarly for `C:\Home\ABC\2.txt` - "`C:\Home\Hello.exe C:\Home\ABC\2.txt`"

Kindly help me how to pass a searched file as an input to execute a command.

Thanks,
Kino

Comment: What have you tried? Some searching around and trial and error would have you on track already.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) (Really now? StackOverflow blocks the "what have you tried" text?)

Comment: Can you explain it better.,

Comment: `file.getAbsolutePath()` - append this to your `Hello.exe` command and execute it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below program as a base and then customize further as per your rqeuirement

```
public class ProcessBuildDemo { 
 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"}; //In place of "dir" you can append the list of file paths that you have
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
    //You can set up your work directory
    probuilder.directory(new File("c:\\xyzwsdemo")); //This is the folder from where the command will be executed.

    Process process = probuilder.start();

    //Read out dir output
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",
            Arrays.toString(command));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    //Wait to get exit value
    try {
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets get you started:

Filter files using: FilenameFilter:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html

Sample:
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=384

And after you have got the files:
Use ProcessBuilder to execute:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Sample:
http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189

Comment: Actually there is more simple than that for filtering. You have a globbing matcher for `DirectoryStream`s!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app from the command line (e.g. windows cmd), and your program name is Hello.java, only thing you have to do is to put in the argument, just like you did in your example. So it looks something like:

```
 java Hello C:\Home\1\1.txt
```

I did not use exe, since this is an example, and the question is tagged with "java" tag.

Your Hello.java MUST have a **main** method that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
}
```

The parameter `args` are the actual parameters you enter in the command line. So to get the file name, you would have to do this:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    String fileName= args[0];
}
```

And that's it. Later on, you can do with that whatever you want, i.e. open and edit a file:

```
File file= new File(fileName);
//do whatever with that file.
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
           String filename;
            try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                filename = "";//read the file na,e
                Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Home\\Hello.exe " + filename );

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                String line=null;

                while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Error "+exitVal);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```